# Can Apache delivers a dynamic resp. static page dependent on cookie/session

Tags: apache, flask, session, flask-login, apache2.4

I want to achieve:

Given a static website with the possibility to login. If logged in the user should see the identical website with some dynamic elements, so the website will be rendered on the fly by Flask. Both sites have the same structure, so every static page has its dynamic counterpart at the same url.

So I have two folders:

- `.../html/staticpage`
- `.../html/flaskpage`

which delivers the static resp. the dynamic site independently, if I point Apache to it.

When the user clicks the login icon on the static page, he is redirected to the login page where Flask-Login is used to set a cookie and establish a session.

Now I want Apache to

1. notice this cookie and
2. if the cookie exists point to the flask
   app and if not return the static page.

Some notes:

- It is not a possibility to just make both dynamic generated!
- I am free to do the cookie/session handling in any way.
- The url should not change, so the user should get the
  `domain.com/products/` wether he is logged in or not. He should not be
  redirect to something like `domain.com/authorized/products/`.

Thanks for helping me